# options menu way off when right click on swf

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

I am having some trouble with click events on a swf object embedded on the page.

-When I single click on a hot spot, nothing happens.

-When I right click, the options menu comes up way off of where my mouse actually is.

Does anyone have any ideas? This is ONLY HAPPENING IN FIREFOX 12.

Here is an example of the issue (on the leader board):
http://cache.boston.com/images/ads/testpages/wbmason042012_clst_PUSHDOWN.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not seeing any leader board but I can certainly say that this page is riddled with flash errors. It looks like it is trying to do some direct addressing of a machine?

```
Error #2044: Unhandled AsyncErrorEvent:. text=Error #2095: flash.net.NetStream was unable to invoke callback onXMPData. error=ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property onXMPData not found on flyover.as$0.CustomClient and there is no default value.
at flyover/connectStream()[C:\Users\dwallace\Documents\HTML5Launchers\flyover\flyover.as:169]
at flyover/netStatusHandler()[C:\Users\dwallace\Documents\HTML5Launchers\flyover\flyover.as:141]
at flash.net::NetConnection/connect()
at flyover()[C:\Users\dwallace\Documents\HTML5Launchers\flyover\flyover.as:129]
```